# How can I route to a specific (sub)-view?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I've created a state with multiple views. Can you tell me how to route to a specific view?

**app.js:**

```
  .state('tabs.movies', {
    url: '/movies',
    views: {
      'movies-tab': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/movies.html',
        controller: 'MoviesCtrl'
      },
      'movies-tab-grid': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/movies_grid.html',
        controller: 'MoviesCtrl'
      },
      'movies-tab-list': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/movies_list.html',
        controller: 'MoviesCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

The three (sub) views are about to show the same content but with different layouts (Slides, Grid, List). I also tried to use ng-switch / ng-if, but whenever I wrap my carousel (ks-swiper-container) with a div-container, it completely disappears. So I thought routing might be the better way.

I would like to create a button to switch the (sub) views like this:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
  <button class="button button-icon ion-grid" ng-click=""></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

I know that routing can be done in several ways (e.g. with a href) but I have no idea how to route to a view instead of a specific state.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.